# Enabling logging in my.cnf on OSX not working

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench, logfile, my.cnf

Pulling my hair out and can't seem to find an answer to my issue. I am running MYSQL 5.6.26 on OSX Yosemite. I am simply trying to enable logging of my queries.

I have located the my.cnf file at /usr/local/mysql and added the two 
lines under [mysql](I actually had to type them out rather than just uncommenting existing lines):

```
general_log=1
general_log_file=/usr/local/mysql/mysql.log
```

Doing a ls -l on my.cnf yields:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  1002 Nov 10 19:01 my.cnf
```

Which seemed strange. Why wouldn't _mysql be the owner?

I have tried first just making the changes above and stopping and restarting the sql server via System Preferences and that doesn't work.

I have tried changing ownership of my.cnf to _mysql, creating mysql.log in the directory /usr/local/mysql and making the owner _mysql also to no avail.

Getting a bit crazy as I feel this should not be that hard. How do I enable logging for mysql?

Comment: see if you have a my.cnf under /var/mysql

Comment: I don't see a mysql directory in /var

Comment: I see that I have two, but maybe neither is being used. Download mysqlworkbench. Under Admin/Configuration you can set logging options.

Comment: Downloaded Work Bench and that with creating changing permissions on the log file did the trick. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking the advice of John Elemans I used mySQL workbench, opened up a local instance, and on the left-hand side is an area called 'Instance' that has a link to 'Server Logs'. The error log was showing that the log file I specified in my.cnf wasn't there. So I created the log file mysql.log in /usr/local/mysql and restarted the server via WorkBench. Looked at the error log and an error was thrown saying mysql couldn't open up the file. Checked permissions and _mysql wasn't the owner. So I did a chown from root to _mysql for the log file, restarted the server again, and voila'... it was working. Thanks all.

Not sure how to accept John's answer as the correct one so I'll just select this one as it answers the issue for others.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this post when trying to setup logging on mySQL 5.7 Community Edition. This version comes with a launch daemon `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist` that replaces the my.cnf file for new installations. You can add in start-up arguments to the plist file to enable logging for:

`--log-output`, `--general_log`, `slow_query_log`, e.g.:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld</string>
        <string>--user=_mysql</string>
        <string>--basedir=/usr/local/mysql</string>
        <string>--datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data</string>
        <string>--plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin</string>
        <string>--pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid</string>
        <string>--log-output=FILE</string>
        <string>--general_log=/var/log/mysql/mysql.log</string>
        <string>--log-error=/var/log/mysql/mysql.err.log</string>
    </array>
```

More info can be found at:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/osx-installation-launchd.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/log-destinations.html

Comment: --general_log parameter expects a boolean value, not a path to the log file. So use --general_log=on instead. By default, MySQL will generate a hostname.log file in /usr/local/mysql/data/.

Comment: Just a **reminder** for anybody using this method: you need to add both `log-bin` and `server-id` options (`server-id=1` can usually do the job). I missed to set `server-id` and the plist gets loaded without starting the mysql server.

Answer (score 0):

By default no config file is used on OSX with the standard installation. If you want the server to pick up one automatically put it into /etc (i.e. /etc/my.cnf), which really ends up in /private/etc/my.cnf, but that is transparent.

Another option is to specify the options file (via the --defaults-file parameter) on startup of the server:

> Mikes-MacBook-Pro:etc Mike$ ps aux | grep mysql
>
> Mike             2055   0,0  0,1  3235892   7268   ??  S     2Nov15
>   1:41.22 /Users/Mike/sandboxes/5.7.5/bin/mysqld
>       --defaults-file=/Users/Mike/sandboxes/msb_5_7_5/my.sandbox.cnf --basedir=/Users/Mike/sandboxes/5.7.5 --datadir=/Users/Mike/sandboxes/msb_5_7_5/data --plugin-dir=/Users/Mike/sandboxes/5.7.5/lib/plugin --user=Mike --log-error=/Users/Mike/sandboxes/msb_5_7_5/data/msandbox.err --pid-file=/Users/Mike/sandboxes/msb_5_7_5/data/mysql_sandbox5705.pid --socket=/var/folders/fv/13zbdzw17cdczn_rbnt5m_140000gn/T//mysql_sandbox5705.sock
>       --port=5705

Comment: I copied the my.cnf in the /usr/local/mysql to /etc and restarted mysql but I did not see a mysql.log file populated in /usr/local/mysql directory.

Permission for my.cnf in /etc is -rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  
Is that an issue?

Comment: Could be, yes. How is the server started (which user account)? Try different error file locations (e.g. in /tmp, your home dir etc.). Also try different port settings and connect from terminal to ensure that server has picked up your my.cnf file actually (or specify it explicitly when starting the server).